Energy and momentum conservation for photon absorption
As an undergrad physics student, I am pondering on this question.
If an (2 level) atom absorbs a single resonant photon, the energy of electronic state increases by $\hbar \omega$. At the same time conservation of momentum states, that the atom must have a nonzero total momentum equal to $\hbar k$ after the interaction and therefore a nonzero kinetic energy. How does this work with energy conservation, which states that the total photon energy is transfered into exciting the electrons?

As you point out, not all of the energy of the photon goes into exciting the electron, Similarly when  stationary atom emits a photon, some of the electon level enenrgy goes into the recoil kinetic energy of the atom and the emited photon has less energy than expected. So in both cases $E_{\rm phton}\ne E_2-E_1$. This is why the suppression of the KE loss by  the Mossbauer effect is important in precssion measurement..
